# jQuery - Stop accordion menu from closing when menu item clicked

Tags: jquery

How do I stop the accordion menu ul.sub-menu from closing when a submenu link is clicked?

The accordion opens fines when the parent item is clicked, but when the submenu item is clicked in the level beneath it, it closes again.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">parent 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1st child item</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">parent 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu current-menu-parent">
        <li><a href="#">2nd child item</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">3rd child item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">parent 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">4th child item</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>    
</ul>​​​​​​​​
```

Here's my jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".menu > li").children("a").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    $('.sub-menu').hide();  
    $('.current-menu-parent').show();    
    $('.menu > li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

Comment: accordion mean when you clicked on menu>li, all other ul will hide and shows which your click... is it you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion for you,

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">parent 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1st child item</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">parent 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu current-menu-item">
        <li><a href="#">2nd child item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3rd child item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">parent 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">4th child item</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>    
</ul>​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.sub-menu{
    display:none;
}
.current-menu-item{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
rel = 0;


$('.sub-menu').hover(function(){ // findind mouse postion
        rel = 1; // if mouse on submenu
    }, function(){ 
        rel = 0;  if mouse out submanu
});
$('.menu > li').live("click",function(){


        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){ // if not already opened
            $('.sub-menu').slideUp();    // hide all other submenu
            $('.sub-menu',this).slideDown();  // show which your clicked
            $(".menu > li").remove('active');  //  remove all active class in li
            $(this).addClass('active'); //adding active class which your clicked li
        }
        else{
            if(rel==0){
                $('.sub-menu').slideUp(); // if clicked already opend parent that will close
                $(this).removeClass('active'); // remove all active class
            }
            else{

            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the sublink pages are already open when the page loads and they close when clicked. Also, it removes the cursor from the parent items and the slide effect.

Comment: now clicking on the parent items does nothing, the accordion stays closed

Comment: ok that works better... but now the accordion closes and opens again when submenu links are clicked. Also, when you click the parent item twice, it closes and opens the submenu again too.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you my friend! you are a genius! By the way, if my submenu item page is open (so the .sub-menu li has a class of '.current-menu-item') is there a way to keep the accordion open for that .sub-menu?

Comment: `Live` is deprecated. Use `.on` but the other answer here seems much simpler

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

Instead of the `return` statement, use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from propagating to the parent.

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(e) {
    if(!$(this).closest('ul').hasClass('menu')) e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qNyR6/1/

---

Adding the below code will work:

```
$('.menu li a').click(function() {
    return $(this).closest('ul').hasClass('menu');
});
```

This will ensure that clicks on your `<a>` tags don't propagate over to the parent `<li>` causing the menu to `slideToggle` (i.e. collapse since it was already in expanded state)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qNyR6/

Comment: Thanks. This works at stopping the accordion from closing again, but it prevents the submenu links from clicking through to their links. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Yes, it opens and closes like an accordion when the parent menu items are clicked.