# JQuery UI Nested Accordion - clicking on child accordion closes the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm implementing a nested accordion, but when I click on a child component within the parent accordion, it closes the parent. I'd like it to remain open when a child is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Sub-Div1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is a sub-div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        header: "> h3:not(.item)",
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Forgot to add, there's a final </div> tag at the end of the HTML. StackOverflow won't let me edit my question for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Stop accordion menu from closing when menu item clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606666/jquery-stop-accordion-menu-from-closing-when-menu-item-clicked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have the same id for both accordions (*which is invalid html to start with*) which makes the plugin always match the first one.

If you use classes it works fine

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Sub-Div1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is a sub-div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    header: "> h3:not(.item)",
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xmq8xhvp/

Comment: This is correct, changing id to class and the # to a fullstop fixed it. Many thanks.

Comment: this almost worked for me, but failed when I had another accordion at the same level as `Home` (i.e. `Home2`). After some tweaking it's working great. Here are my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/5e3fquxr/1/

Answer (score 2):

just used your code to fix the same problem and it worked straight away, thanks.

Not sure why it works though -

```
header: "> h3:not(.item)",
```

I read the above as:
For the header, get the direct child h3s (after class="accordion), but not (.item).

So, .item must refer to the nested accordion class's direct child?  Is .item a reserved jquery word? I've googled it but haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

As [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) and [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values) specification says:
You should not have more than one element has the same id attribute.

So, change your parent or child element id attribute and i promise you will be fine.